# How to hide element using Class; instead of using css function in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

There are multiple times datatables are used in solution.

At one place we got into requirement where we need to hide data table header:

```
<div id="DocTable_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper no-footer">
<div>
 <div class="dataTables_scroll">
  //Following is top div of head which is generated dynamically by datatables
  <div class="dataTables_scrollHead noDisplay" style="overflow: hidden; position: relative; border: 0px none; width: 100%;">
     <div class="dataTables_scrollHeadInner" style="box-sizing: content-box; width: 1188px; padding-right: 16px;">
       <table class="dataTable no-footer" role="grid" style="margin-left: 0px; width: 1188px;">
          <thead id="DocHeading">
          </thead>
```

I have added a style named **noDisplay** in dataTables_scrollHead.

It contains :

```
noDisplay{
display:none !important;
}
```

I am applying it in JQuery as:

```
$(".dataTables_scrollHead").addClass("noDisplay");
```

When i run the code the Header does not hide. 
In firebug i am able to see the style name. In firebug, when i try to apply class to div below it; it is not getting applied.

In firebug, When i use inline style display:none in style tag. It hides.

But when i used

```
$(".dataTables_scrollHead").css('display', 'none');
```

It worked.

Why?

As per standards we are not suppose to use .css and to use addClass only. Anyone please help me in doing the same using addclass?

Comment: have you wrapped the code in dom ready event?

Comment: `.noDisplay{
display:none !important;
}` not `noDisplay{
display:none !important;
}`. dot is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps a typo in your CSS?

Your CSS:

```
noDisplay{
display:none !important;
}
```

Your forgot the **.** :

```
.noDisplay{
display:none !important;
}
```

[EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/1qzu2f3f/)